# ldap prevent brute force

Tags: ldap, brute-force-attacks

The title should be self explanatory but more in detail I'm looking for a way to protect the ldap from LAN brute force attacks.

It would be fine to prevent password guessing by locking a password for a specified period of time after repeated authentication failures. It doesn't matter if this can be turned into a DOS.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this and the documents I've found are really confused.

Comment: what LDAP server?  What OS/  This seems like something that is likely to be very closely tied to a specific implementation.  For example, you could probably do something with fail2ban on a Linux system.  Or maybe do some kind of rate-limiting with iptables.  Your LDAP server may have built-in rate limiting features, or maybe not.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Openldap on debian. @Zoredache thanks for the tip: I'll dig about fail2ban

Comment: I found something interesting here. http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html

I'll do some tests and then I'll report something